# MYSQL not allowing JSON data type

Tags: mysql, json, xampp

I'm trying to add a column of type JSON to one of my tables. I'm using XAMPP with phpmyadmin. The server version is 10.1.31-MariaDB. The innodb version is 5.6.36-83.0

When i try to select the JSON type from the select-box in phpmyadmin, i do not see anything about JSON. Also, running this query results in a "syntax error":

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD `some_column` json;
```

I've seen both in the manual, and in various tutorials, that mysql indeed does support JSON type.

Is it a version issue? To be honest, i'm very confused about the whole mysql versioning situation. I see on Wikipedia, that the latest stable release is 8.0.11, whereas mine seems to be something completely different(i dont know which is relevant: the "server" or the "innodb" version) I would assume that XAMPP uses the latest mysql version, but maybe i'm wrong.

Can someone shed some light on the issue? If it is actually a version thing, would it be possible to upgrade, while still using XAMPP?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that this data type is only available from MariaDB version 10.2.7. You can use LONGTEXT instead, because according to the docs JSON is only an alias for LONGTEXT.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a version issue, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

You're using MariaDB 10.1, which is based on MySQL 5.6/5.7 (hence the innodb version).  But the JSON data type was added in MySQL 8.0.  It looks like as of this time MariaDB doesn't support the JSON data type.

Comment: I see. Well, i will just go with Ebby's recommendation of using LONGTEXT.

Comment: "But the JSON data type was added in MySQL 8.0" No the JSON datatype was already added in MySQL in version 5.7 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html .. MySQL 8.0 added more JSON functions to work with JSON.

Comment: Well Raymond, my mysql version is 5.6 . I do not understand how come XAMPP ships with such an old version

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data type as added in version 5.7 and is improved in 8. MariaDB does not have a JSON data type